# Will wind blowing perpendicular to the path of motorbike, topple a slow moving bike or fast moving bike?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, kinematics

So, I am riding a Motorbike on a windy day.

I am traveling from North to South and winds were blowing from East to west.

Should I drive slow or fast to avoid getting toppled down by the winds?

Also, is there a way to calculate the safest speed if my motorbike weights 100 kg and wind is blowing at 80 KM/hour?

Answer (score 2):

High speed makes a bike more stable whether you deal with a wind or with other disturbances.

One of the factors is a gyroscoping effect of the wheels: the greater the speed, the more difficult it is to change the orientation of the wheels and therefore of the bike.

Another factor is the ease of correction. If, due to the wind or other disturbances, the bike does lean, at higher speed, the required turn of the front wheel, to counter the torque of the weight with the matching centrifugal force, would be less than at a lower speed.

Regardless of the speed, if the wind is constant, you'll have to shift your weight or slightly lean into the wind.

Of course, when speed gets too high, other effects, like loss of traction, may become significant, and, therefore, it would be difficult to determine the optimal speed for safety.

Comment: Plus, the faster you go forward, the more the angle-of-attack changes -- the effective wind velocity is the sum of both vectors. So moving quickly changes it from a 90 degree angle of attack to something much smaller.

Comment: Gyroscopic action contributes very little to the stability of the bike as compared to the active steering by the rider. Higher speeds make the steering more responsive. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_and_motorcycle_dynamics#Balance